# django unicode url for multibyte special characters

Tags: django, character

I am trying to create and edit share folder using these special mutibyte characters ＠＠, ああ,@@　, ＃＃.
I am able to create but for editing i am receiving 400 request as it is redirecting to another view.

Please help on this.

Comment: Did you put # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- to the first line of file which creates folder?

Comment: yes.. I have put in all views.But it is not redirecting ot respective view as pattern is not matched in url.py